# Getting "IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)" when querying "select * from open"

Tags: c#, sql, jet

I have my C# app connected to Jet 4.0 engine. When I run the query "select * from open" (I think "open" is a keyword and this is why I'm getting an exception, but...) I get this exception: "IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)". I usually get more human readable exceptions telling me what is wrong with my query. This one looks more like a bug in the Jet engine. I just tested in Microsoft Access 2002 to run the same query and it treats "open" as a perfectly valid name. I can create a table named "open" and do whatever I want with it. I just need to know if it's a bug in the Jet engine so I can go ahead and replace the weired looking message for a human readable one and show that to the user, or if there is a problem with my code.

Comment: I can't answer your question but in interactive Access you have a different set of reserved words than you do when using ADO/OLEDB, unless you have SQL 92 mode turned on in Access (which you likely don't since it's not the default, and which would not be advisable if you were trying to build a front end using Access). I don't know if OPEN is a reserved word in the one and not in the other, but I just wanted to correct your assumption that running the SQL in internactive Access proves that it's OK when run from outside Access.

Answer (score 5):

I have been through the same problem, try enclosing the reserved word in square brackets i.e.:

```
"select * from [open]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the below sql in excel:

```
"select * from [open$]"
```

Maybe you can try it.